# MySQL: Ignore a Row in a table of a particular Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, master-slave-replication, mariadb-10.3

I had replication in place between 3 databases, I am trying to ignore a Row in a table of a particular Database. I tried many ways but i couldn't, and also i couldn't find anything in online that helps me all i see is how to ignore a table in replication but not a row of a table. 
please someone help me regarding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might help if you explain why you need to "ignore a row" and what that means to you.

Comment: In that row url of server from where alert comes resides, when it replicates it overrides the values which is not supposed to be